# How to open different man page section in VIM (with K shortcut)?

Tags: vim, manpage

Often times, there are name overloading for man page sections. For example, I tried to lookup

```
getopt(...)
```

with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and vim opened `GETOPT(1)` but actually I wanted `GETOPT(3)` because I'm writing C-program.

Is there a way to specify which man page section to open in VIM?

Comment: Did you even try to read the documentation for `K`? See `:help K`.

Comment: You're right... I should've done it before I posted. 3K is what I'm looking for. I'll close this question.

Comment: Doesn't look like I can close on my own. I can either delete or leave this open. (Perhaps it will still help others.)

Comment: Better: answer it yourself.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to romainl, I looked up vim help and the proper way to do it is

```
<section number>K
```

i.e. 3K under getopt will open GETOPT(3).